# Is there any method to make if else shorter to this code?

Tags: c#

```
if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("Home") == false)
{               
    result_show.richTextBox1.Text += "Home in Home Menu is missing.";
}

if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("Users") == false)
{               
    result_show.richTextBox1.Text += "Users in Home Menu is missing.";
}

if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("Space") == false)
{               
    result_show.richTextBox1.Text += "Space in Home Menu is missing.";
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39720620/
Or you can scroll down to see the answer that meet the right of my need. Appreciate for this.

Comment: Is the text to add always the same?

Comment: If the text is the same, simply create a collection of words and use Linq - `Any` for example. If text is different, use dictionary to associate keyword with text and use a loop to iterate through dictionary.

Comment: You may as well just run a list through avoid method to check the list of items using a foreach/for-loop statement.

Comment: Create a `List` of the words you want to check, and then loop through them and check. I suggest doing some research on loops... you should really be able to think of this approach without asking others

Comment: First thing to do is stop using `== false` and use `!`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var list = new List<TextAndMessage>()
{
    new TextAndMessage {TextToCompare = "Home", Message = "Home in Home Menu is missing."},
    new TextAndMessage {TextToCompare = "Users", Message = "Home in Home Menu is missing."}
};

var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (!richTextBox1.Text.Contains(item.TextToCompare))
    {
        sb.Append(item.Message);
    }
}
//Assigning at the end, as you might falsely check that the string is contained in textbox, that has come from one of the messages.
result_show.richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

and

```
public class TextAndMessage
{
    public string TextToCompare { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's very useful for me~~

Thank you~ I will add something to compact it as much as it can. 
:D

Answer (score 2):

```
string template = "{0} in Home Menu is missing.";
string[] keywords = new string[] { "home", "users", "space" };
for (int i = 0; i < keywords.Length; i++)
{
    result_show.richTextBox1.Text += richTextBox1.Text.Contains(keywords[i]) ?
             string.Empty : string.Format(template, keywords[i]);
}
```

use **StringBuilder** if you need some performance

Comment: You will have to switch the branches of that conditional statement: you want the error message appended when the text does NOT contain the keyword.

Comment: @HansKesting: Good spot! But it's too late for me to remove my upvote, I guess I should just edit the answer instead then

Comment: that could / should be a foreach loop...

Comment: @Vogel612: Sure it *could* be, but whether it *should* be is just a matter of opinion/preference... it's perfectly fine as it is

Comment: @musefan at this point this looks to me like you're trying to start a fight by agreeing, which is frankly speaking unsettling...

Comment: @Vogel612: Nope it's just a comment. Just thinking out loud. Nothing more, nothing less

Answer (score -1):

```
 Dictionary<string,string> Messages = new Dictionary<string,string> {"...."};

 var sb = new StringBuilder();

 Messages.ForEach(p=>
 {
    if(p.Key.Contains(richTextBox1.Text))
    {
     sb.Append(P.value);
    } 
 });
```

Comment: Although a valid answer I would recommend you include the actual Dictionary definitions. Purely because it helps clarify exactly how you intend it to work. In this case the OP is clearly unfamiliar with dictionaries so it's unlikely they will know what you mean by `{"...."}`

Comment: Code only answers are not good answers, try adding a few lines explaining what the problem was and how your code fixes it

Answer (score -3):

Please use following pattern:

```
Dictionary<string, string> wordsToCompare = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Home", "Home in Home Menu is missing." },
    { "Users", "Even another string here" },
    ...
};

private string GetSuffixString(string word)
{
    string resultString;
    wordsToCompare.TryGetValue(word, out resultString);
    return resultString;
}
```

Then use it:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(result_show.richTextBox1.Text);
builder.Append(this.GetSuffixString(richTextBox1.Text));
result_show.richTextBox1.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: This is not a complete solution... it doesn't do anything

Comment: Now it should be complete

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure it achieves the goals. OP code suggests building a list if there is multiple matches. It also should use "contain" and not be a exact match